# Requirejs with jquery in Single Page Application

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am learning RequireJS, in the process I am stuck with the below problem:

I am trying to implement a single page application. Below scenario considered is similar to actual problem.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="require.js" data-main="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <div id="buttonContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require([  'jquery' ], function( $) {
    $(function() {
        $("#start").click(function() {
            $("#buttonContainer").load("page1.html");
            require(['module1'],function(){});
        }); 
    });
});
```

**page1.html**

```
<div>
    <button id="button_1">Click Me!!</button>
</div>
```

**module1.js**

```
define(['jquery'],function($){
    $(function(){
        $("#button_1").click(function(){
            $("#buttonContainer").load("page2.html");
        require(['module2'],function(){});
        });
    });
});
```

**page2.html**

```
<div>
    <button id="button_2">Back</button>
</div>
```

**module2.js**

```
define(['jquery'],function($){
    $(function(){
        $("#button_2").click(function(){
            $("#buttonContainer").load("page1.html");
        require(['module1'],function(){});
        });
    });
});
```

On click of **start** in **index.html** the div is populated with **Click me!!**, on click of **Click me!!** the div is populated with **Back** button and on click of **Back** button again **Click me!!** is populated and viceversa.

On jquery load of html, I am calling require()..to call respective js function for html. Is my approach correct??

Comment: Does your code run correctly? if so, your approach is correct. If not, what's the error message from your javascript debugger?

Comment: Yes my code runs..the click events get registred only for the first time. Sequence is on click of Start --> Click me!! --> Back --> Click me!! after this sequence when I click on Click me!! the click event on this button(button_1) is not getting fired.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong. Your code would work if requiring `module1` and `module2` would execute the module's factory *every* time your code requires the modules. However, the way RequireJS works, a module's factory is executed only the *first* time a module is required. (The "factory" is the callback you pass to `define` when defining a module.)

It's not clear to me what warrants dividing the code into modules the way it is done in the question. It seems unnecessary.

If there is a reason to divide into modules the way it is done in the question, then I would make the modules act on the page *only* when function is called. Then `module1.js` could be something like:

```
define(['jquery', 'module2'], function ($, module2) {
    return function () {
           // Whatever actions I want...
    };
});
```

`module2` would be structured like `module1`. `main.js` would be something like:

```
require(['jquery', 'module1'], function ($, module1) {
    $(function () {
        [...]
         // This calls the function you returned when defining module 1.
        module1();
        [...]
    });
});
```

Comment: I was adding the code to my answer while you sent your commend. Look again.

Comment: module1.js and module2.js having 'define' with dependencies on jquery, module2 and jquery, module1 didn't work I had to call require(['module2']) in define of module1.js and require(['module1')] in define of module2.js after loading html.